# Crystal Reports Header Subreport Data vanishes when new field is added to DataTable

Tags: xsd, crystal-reports, dataset, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I apologize if my example is a little vague; Unfortunately, I can't use the same field names in my example without giving away both the company name and the purpose of the data.

Given the following:

A Crystal Report populated by a dataset and bound to an XSD schema file;

A .Net 1.1 program which populates the dataset and binds it to the report;

Data Tables Foo and Bar;

XSD Schema:

```
----Foo----
Stuff (pk)
Things
Gunk

----Bar----
Stuff (fk)
Details
Widget
```

Relationship: One Foo can have 1 or more Bars, Inner Join on Stuff.

This report already works.  There's been a request to add a new "code" field to the report to indicate a certain value tied to contracts.   There is a list of codes, and a list of parts that have specific codes.  This meant, on the database side, adding a table with "Widget" and "CodeID" as a linking table, indicating which code goes with which widget, and a table with "CodeID" and "CodeDescr" to hold the codes and their definitions.  I was able to add the field by modifying the schema file to add "CodeDescr" to Bar and populating it with a simple query based on that row's value in "Widget".   This also works.

The problem is the subreport that makes up the header.  It uses the same XSD file, but if the CodeDescr field is added to the subreport that makes up the body of the report, all values in the header vanish.   Some of these values are literals (i.e. the value of "Stuff" to identify the item) and others are formulae (such as using the value of Gunk to determine whether to display a string or a numeric identifier).  I've been banging my head on the desk for 3 days trying to figure out why this stopped populating so I can fix it.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I've solved the puzzle of your variable names enough to maybe start helping :)

Can you draw up a goal in Excel to help make sure we're aiming in the right direction?

To confirm, this is your database, joining on colors:

[image]

Some random thoughts aimed at helping:

- Shouldn't necessarily matter, but are you constructing your subreport in its header as well? Or in its details? I typically try to match them, though as long as your suppressions are correct it shouldn't matter.
- Right click on your subreport (while on the design tab), select "Change Subreport Links" Are the expected links there?
- After checking your links, go into your subreport and check its Record Select. Changing links adds a new line for each link in here. Is the logic correct? On that note, can you transpose your parent report and subreport's record selects to the variables used in your example for us to look at here?

I'll come back to this as time allows, let us know when you have an update.

Comment: You got the associations perfectly.  All subreports use the Details section, so that matches up.  I forgot to mention, however, that the only editor at my disposal is the godawful one that is built into Visual Studio 2003.  I did check the links and they are as expected.  I tried with a Left Outer join after these problems cropped up and had no more success than an Inner Join.  This also means I don't have a conventional "Record Select" and the entire dataset is assembled in VB.Net.    All that was changed there is a single method that gets the result of an SQL statement that calls the tables.

Comment: Understood. To be fair, this is probably where my knowledge drops off. While we often rub elbows, VB.NET and I aren't on close terms. My suggestion from here would be that, since this doesn't sound like an overly complex report, you could try drawing it up in Crystal Reports' GUI and see if you still have trouble. That being said, someone with VB.NET know-how might be able to help you get to a more reasonable/desirable solution. Good luck, I'll keep an eye on your question in case it drifts back toward my area

Answer (score 0):

This was finally resolved by, instead of creating new tables in the XSD file, adjusting the queries called by the XSD file to pull in the new value as part of the existing tables.